# Continue a download if timestamp has not changed

Tags: wget, timestamps

I'd like to mirror a site with large, updating database dumps. I don't entirely understand the `-N` and `-c` options and how they combine after reading the `wget` man page.

Is there a way to download a file, preferably with wget, so that:

- if the server's timestamp is newer than the local one, the download replaces the local file
- if the server's timestamp is the same as the local one, but the remote size is larger, wget continues the download

I happen to know the server supports sending modification times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wget manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/wget-1.8.1/html_chapter/wget_5.html) has some more information than `man wget`:

> A file is considered new if one of these two conditions are met:
>
> 1. A file of that name does not already exist locally.
> 2. A file of that name does exist, but the remote file was modified more recently than the local file.
>
> To implement this, the program needs to be aware of the time of last modification of both local and remote files. We call this information the time-stamp of a file.
>
> The time-stamping in GNU Wget is turned on using `--timestamping` (`-N`) option, or through timestamping = on directive in `.wgetrc`. With this option, for each file it intends to download, Wget will check whether a local file of the same name exists. If it does, and the remote file is older, Wget will not download it.
>
> If the local file does not exist, or the sizes of the files do not match, Wget will download the remote file no matter what the time-stamps say.

In short, `-N` should do what you ask.